# Unsupported item key in Zabbix discovery

Tags: zabbix

I am using zabbix 4.0.
Trying to make discovery with simple check.
When i click "check now", i get Unsupported item key warning. Below you can find my discovery configuration. I couldnt solve why does it give this error. Everything seems fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you have set a `Simple Check` type, then typed in a `ssh.run...` key.

[SSH checks](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/ssh_checks) type must be configured as `SSH Agent`, which also enables the `executed script` box: this command must return a json formatted according to the LLD format.

Answer (score -1):

The key items to verify are:

- the feature is supported for passive checks only
- the check must be present in configuration cache in order to get executed

To refresh the configuration cache, execute `zabbix_server -R config_cache_reload` (or `zabbix_proxy -R config_cache_reload`).

Reference: [check_now](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/check_now).